# Album Artwork and representativeItem

Tags: ios6

I'm trying to put a placeholder image if the album art doesn't exist. For some reason the image from representativeItem is never null so it simply assigns a blank artwork...

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [[mediaListItem representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

    if (artwork) {
         sModel.albumImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (10, 10)];
    } else {
        sModel.albumImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default_.png"]; //never enters
    }
```

Comment: So you claim that `if (artwork)` should enter the `else` side if the `pointer to artwork == 0`?  The intent of your code could be clearer than this.

Comment: If the artwork exists then it sets the album image with <artwork>. Otherwise it sets a default image, I can't see how I can make this clearer for you.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the most likely cause of the `else` never getting executed is that the condition in your `if` is wrong.  It looks like you're checking for `artwork` being zero, but who knows what's at that pointer if you don't get an `artwork` reference.

Comment: Ah I see. Well the documentation doesn't specify any detail on return values so I guess I'm stuck until I see what this method returns if it can't find proper artwork.

Comment: I'm not an ios6 expert, but since it appears that you'll always get an `MPMediaItemArtwork` object from this call, you'll have to check the [documentation for MPMediaItemArtwork](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItemArtwork_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008212) and see if there's something there you can use to detect the absence of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I'm a genius ;)

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [[mediaListItem representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

//If artwork has no size set place holder
if (CGSizeEqualToSize(artwork.bounds.size, CGSizeZero))
{
   sModel.albumImage = [UIImage imageNamed:DEFAULT_IMG];
}
else //Otherwise set the artwork found in the library. 
{
   sModel.albumImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (SIZE_X, SIZE_Y)];
}
```